# GNOME 3 not loading any icons or wallpaper and crashing

Tags: gnome, icons, desktop-background

Something weird happened: first during login  my profile image was not showing, then I put in the password and it didn't log in, I had to cancel and do it once again to log in. Then the desktop showed up but with black wallpaper, many icons missing on the top bar and none of the applications icons, and if I try to open a terminal or anything else it crashes and take me back to the log in screen.

Update: Now after updating the system it's not even loading the login screen.

Comment: Your `/home` partition may be full or you may have permissions issue. Do a `ls -la ~` at tty session (Ctrl-Alt-F1) to see if you are owner of all objects within in fact.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with GNOME on Ubuntu. I fixed it with these steps.

On the login screen press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to switch to a TTY.

I tried to update with `sudo apt update` but it failed due to some error saying something like `bad return status for module build on kernel`.

Update failed so we need to reconfigure packages

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then upgrade

```
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and remove not required packages

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo reboot
```

After this GNOME showed everything fine and stopped crashing.